# Code functionality breaks when adding actual content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the dummy code which works fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="display: inline-block; width:250px;">Logo Image</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="sideNav">
      <li id="campaignsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Campaigns</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="subscribersNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Subscribers</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="reportsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Reports</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="campaignsPage">
      <p>This is campaign Page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="subscribersPage">
      <p>This is subscribers page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reportsPage">
      <p>MUSIC PAGE reports</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
$('#campaignsPage, #subscribersPage, #reportsPage').hide();

$("#sideNav li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

But when I add actual content in div:

```
<div id="campaignsPage">
      <p>My actual code with a form and multiple container to hold other information.</p>
    </div>
```

The above working code stops and on every click of menu item which is earlier showing different content stops. Can anyone suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add snippet for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> ```
> $("#wrapper").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
> ```

`find` looks through **all descendants** in a depth-first traversal (document order). It's fine when you just have your template, but when you put your real content in (with `div`s, presumably), you mess it up.

You can fix it by using `.children` rather than `.find`. Example:

```js
$('#campaignsPage, #subscribersPage, #reportsPage').hide();

$("#sideNav li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").children("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="display: inline-block; width:250px;">Logo Image</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="sideNav">
      <li id="campaignsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Campaigns</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="subscribersNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Subscribers</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="reportsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Reports</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="campaignsPage">
      This is campaign Page
      <div>I'm a div</div>
      <div>I'm another div</div>
    </div>
    <div id="subscribersPage">
      <p>This is subscribers page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reportsPage">
      <p>MUSIC PAGE reports</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, I wouldn't do it that way. You're already relating the sections by `id` (`campaignsNav` controls `campaignsPage`, etc.), so I'd probably just relate them that way:

```
$("#sideNav li").click(function() {
  var target = "#" + this.id.replace(/Nav$/, "Page");
  $(target).siblings().hide().end().show();
});
```

Example:

```js
$('#campaignsPage, #subscribersPage, #reportsPage').hide();

$("#sideNav li").click(function() {
  var target = "#" + this.id.replace(/Nav$/, "Page");
  $(target).siblings().hide().end().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="display: inline-block; width:250px;">Logo Image</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="sideNav">
      <li id="campaignsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Campaigns</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="subscribersNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Subscribers</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li id="reportsNav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>Reports</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="campaignsPage">
      This is campaign Page
      <div>I'm a div</div>
      <div>I'm another div</div>
    </div>
    <div id="subscribersPage">
      <p>This is subscribers page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reportsPage">
      <p>MUSIC PAGE reports</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other options would be `data-*` attributes, etc.

Comment: Thanks T.J Crowder, you are awesome bro thanks for your quick and exact solution.